# How to use VBA to store formula but only paste values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to figure out how to use VBA to automate my workbook

I've tried to use another sheet to put all the formula and use that sheet to paste the values into another sheet

I want to use macro to do calculations so i can eliminate the additional sheet by the end product is that the main sheet does not have formula, the formula is stored in the VBA.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you tell us what did you try so far? Generally speaking, you can use worksheet functions in VBA. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic) link.

Comment: @EganWolf so far i have 2 separate work sheet one for populating past months data and one for this month data with all the formula. so what i'm doing is that i use the sheet with one month data i will append below to the sheet with all the month but my boss say its too many sheet, she want only one sheet which is the one with all the data, she want to have vba to store the formula then append the values.

Comment: Have you asked the boss why "its too many sheet"?  Using VBA to evaluate worksheet functions and populate cells is always going to be slower than calling the functions directly on sheet.  Also a maintenance nightmare - changing formulas in the code needs a VBA coder instead of an end-user.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Hey bro, do you know how to vlookup in vba referencing from another workbook . i tried this range("E2")=application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(range("A2"),"https://-/[-.xlsx]--'!range("A:BO"),2,FALSE),"")
but not sure why it isn't working, keep giving me syntax error

Comment: Do you have the other workbook open when using code to enter the formula?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Nope

Comment: If you type the formula into `E2` without the other workbook open it will `#REF!` error.  If you open the other workbook, does the error go away?

Comment: the vlookup is workable in formula even if the workbook is not open

Comment: Last try. What do you get if you paste `application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(range("A2"),"https://-/[-.xlsx]--'!range("A:BO"),2,FALSE),"")` with the names exactly as you have in your code into the Immediate pane in the VBA IDE?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald syntax error :(

Answer (score 0):

Below are some ideas:

```
Option Explicit

Sub te()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Method 1 - Example how to get the average of Range("A1:A10") and paste it on .Range("C1")
        .Range("C1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range("A1:A10"))

        'Method 2 - Copy  the value from .Range("C1") which includes formula calculation and paste to .Range("D1") as value
        .Range("C1").Copy
        .Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to not show the cell with formula like have the formula inside the vba only?

Comment: I'm using this way now

Comment: @LimYiLong you can make the calculation as per method 2.

Comment: but i need the whole sheet with no formula

Comment: @LimYiLong as i have mention in my answer, i provide some ideas. Study them and  modify to meet your needs.